# function to Get whole month dates based on day name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I am trying to disable all the dates in a month based on user selected day
eg: if user selects monday, i need to disable all monday.

so i have this function which takes 3 arguments(month, year and array of disabled day). Looks its working until i have disabled array with

```
  [
    "Monday",
    "Tuesday",
    "Wednesday",
    "Thursday",
    "Friday",
    "Saturday",
  ]
```

eg: i have this argument month is  3,
year is 2021, and days as above array.

```
    const getDaysInMonth = (month, year, days) => {


    let pivot = moment().month(month).year(year).startOf("month");
    const end = moment().month(month).year(year).endOf("month");

    let dates = {};
    const disabled = { disabled: true, disableTouchEvent: true };
    while (moment(pivot).isBefore(end)) {
      days.forEach((day) => {
        dates[pivot.day(day).format("YYYY-MM-DD")] = disabled;
      });
      pivot.add(7, "days");
    }

    console.log("before return is", dates);

    return dates;
  };
```

with this function i am not getting dates after "24th saturday" that is last week dates are missing.

Comment: the answer didn't helped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will output all disabled days in your month

```
const getDaysInMonth = (month, year, days) => {
    const endDay = moment()
      .year(year)
      .month(month - 1)
      .endOf("month")
    return Array.from({ length: 31 }).reduce((acc, _, i) => {
      const date = moment()
        .month(month - 1)
        .year(year)
        .startOf("month")
        .add(i, "day")
      const day = date.format("dddd")
      if (days.includes(day) && date.isSameOrBefore(endDay))
        acc = [...acc, date.format("YYYY-MM-DD")]
      return acc
    }, [])
  }
  const result = getDaysInMonth(4, 2021, [
    "Monday",
    "Tuesday",
    "Wednesday",
    "Thursday",
    "Friday",
    "Saturday",
  ])
  console.log(result)
```